# What is the maximum supported data rate for PCIe?

Tags: bandwidth, pci-express

Given a particular generation and link width, how can I determine what the maximum bandwidth is?

I've looked across the Internet and various unofficial sources appear to disagree on the numbers.

- https://www.naplestech.com/bus-speeds.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bit_rates#Computer_buses

Comment: Can you be more specific about your hardware please - or is this just homework?

Comment: @Chopper3: I'm looking for an answer based on PCIe specifications, not any particular hardware connected to the slot.

Comment: Why though? I'm interested in your requirement, it's usually one of the things everyone on serverfault puts in their questions. Plus we could do with some qualification, what speed/number of channels etc.?

Comment: @Chopper3: Well in particular, I'm running a sanity check on some config files for a large cluster of servers. One of the entries involves warning levels for PCIe bandwidth (if bandwidth too low, give a warning). Thus I need to make sure that the warning levels have sane values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Citing [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express)

> Capacity
>
> Per lane (each direction):
>
> ```
> v1.x: 250 MB/s (2.5 GT/s)
> v2.x: 500 MB/s (5 GT/s)
> v3.0: 1 GB/s (8 GT/s)
> v4.0: 2 GB/s (16 GT/s)
> ```
>
> 16 lane slot (each direction):
>
> ```
> v1.x: 4 GB/s (40 GT/s)
> v2.x: 8 GB/s (80 GT/s)
> v3.0: 16 GB/s (128 GT/s)
> ```

Comment: Perfect. I actually have no idea how I missed that since I definitely looked at that page.